# Migrating from jarsigner to apksigner

Tags: android, apksigner

We are currently signing our Android apps using `jarsigner` but we want to migrate to using `apksigner` so we can take advantage of it's additional benefits such as the v2 signing algorithm.

Are there any considerations we need to factor into this migration or is it as simple as changing which tool we are using? Our main concern is obviously to avoid any complications when pushing updated apps to the Play Store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be a simple switch without complications.